# An association field cannot be used in an update item's path expression Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.1

I am using Spring Data JPA and JPQL query. When trying to execute the below update query, getting the below error. How we can solved this problems?

**Query:**

```
@Query("UPDATE EmployeeSrc e SET e.employeeStat.employeeStatStatCd =?1, e.UpdtDt =?2, e.UpdtUserId =?3 "
            + "WHERE e.employeeStat.employeeStatStatCd =?4 AND e.EmpployeeNam =?5")
    public void updateXXXXXXXXX(Long employeeStatStatCd, Date UpdtDt, String lstUpdtUserId, 
            Long employeeStatStatCd, String employeeName);
```

**Error:**

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.2.v20151217-774c696): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Problem compiling [UPDATE EmployeeSrc e SET e.EmployeeStat.EmployeeStatCd =?1, e.UpdtDt =?2, e.UpdtUserId =?3 WHERE e.EmployeeStat.EmployeeStatCd =?4 AND e.EmployeeName =?5]. 
[20, 49] An association field cannot be used in an update item's path expression.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildException(HermesParser.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.validate(HermesParser.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.populateQueryImp(HermesParser.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.jpql.HermesParser.buildQuery(HermesParser.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.buildEJBQLDatabaseQuery(EJBQueryImpl.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EJBQueryImpl.<init>(EJBQueryImpl.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1614)
    ... 61 more
```

Comment: From documentation: "Update queries can only update attributes of the object or its embeddables, its relationships cannot be updated."  Is it your case?http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/queries002.htm

Comment: you can retrieve the EmployeeSrc object and set fields programmatically, i think.

Comment: Right, relationship needs to be define other way around

Comment: And be aware, although it's not relate to your question, but for update and delete Queries you must define `@Modifying` and `@Transactional` annotations.

Comment: Agree !! Noted at my side